# How can I bind attached properties to attached properties in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, attached-properties

In compliance with the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements:

```
public class Attachable {
    protected static readonly DependencyProperty
        ColorAnimationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ColorAnimation", typeof( ColorAnimation ),
            typeof( Attachable ), new PropertyMetadata( new ColorAnimation ) );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        StartColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "StartColor", typeof( Color ), typeof( Attachable ),
            new PropertyMetadata( Colors.White ) ),
        EndColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "EndColor", typeof( Color ), typeof( Attachable ),
            new PropertyMetadata( Colors.Black ) );

    public static Color GetStartColor( FrameworkElement source ) =>
        ( Color )( source.GetValue( StartColorProperty ) );
    public static void SetStartColor( FrameworkElement target, object value ) =>
        target.SetValue( StartColorProperty, value );
    public static Color GetEndColor( FrameworkElement source ) =>
        ( Color )( source.GetValue( EndColorProperty ) );
    public static void SetEndColor( FrameworkElement target, object value ) =>
        target.SetValue( EndColorProperty, value );

    protected static ColorAnimation GetColorAnimation( FrameworkElement source ) =>
        source.GetValue( ColorAnimationProperty ) as ColorAnimation;
}
```

Use in XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="MCVE.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MCVE"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    l:Attachable.StartColor="White" l:Attachable.EndColor="Black" />
```

I want the windows attached `StartColor` and `EndColor` properties to serve as the source for the Start and End values of its own attached `ColorAnimation` value automatically, without having to specify in XAML by assigning a new `ColorAnimation` to the `ColorAnimation` property and setting up the bindings.

I know that I could write in a couple `DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler` methods to assign the new values to the animation when the property changes, but that feels somewhat clunky and awkward to me, and I was hoping there was a different way of doing that.

### Edit 1

To clarify my purpose, what I want is for a read-only `ColorAnimation` to be made available for each instance of the `FrameworkElement` that will use that `FrameworkElement`s attached `StartColor` and `EndColor` property values for its own `From` and `To` values, respectively. So, I would NOT want each control to have to define its own attached `ColorAnimation`, but rather, have each individual control that makes use of this have its own `ColorAnimation` by default, and only that one `ColorAnimation`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to provide an attached ColorAnimation, where you then go back an reconfigure the start and end colors? Do you want to provide start and end colors to a hard coded ColorAnimation? This is quite confusing but I kind of feel like I see what you're trying to accomplish; just not lol. Please update the question with requirements, step by step and if no one else helps I can definitely assist.

Comment: A problem here is that you're using a single ColorAnimation instance for all elements where the ColorAnimation property is supposed to be set. Your "read only" attached property with a value initialized by dependency property metadata won't work for more than one UI element at a time.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII See edit. I hope that makes this more clear.

Comment: @Will So let me make sure I'm on the same page... If and only if you use the attachable StartColor / EndColor properties then you're control will render an attached default ColorAnimation that also correlates to those start / end colors?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Yes, correct.

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a minute and I'm sure you've solved this.. If not I can write the code and show you by example... But I'm thinking and why not just provide a ColorAnimation attachable property?  Then you just attach a full color animation to an object and run it however you're choosing to run it. I see you're saying you don't want that in the question but why is confusing me. I can't understand a use case to avoid it.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks but I got it figured out. I couldn't use a dependencyproperty to source an animation because doing so put the animation in a "read-only" state, so trying to update the animation resulted in an error. As for why, I'm working with an animation that is a bit more complex than a simple color animation. Anyway, the issue has been resolved. Thanks though.